# Page not working Attempt to unlock a mutex which is locked by another thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pthreads, webrick

I want to start my app and it's still "loading". It worked in the morning, but now it doesn't .

I tryied with other ports, switching to a stable branch, restarting computer, but nothing seems to work. On other apps, it's working.  If I stop de server this is the error I see(in the browser)

```
Attempt to unlock a mutex which is locked by another thread
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2012-11-10) at localhost:3000
```

Comment: Fortunately, restarting the server worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem lately. It looks like there are two view partials calling each other in a loop.

Go to the view which is called when you visit the root path and try commenting out any calls to 'render'.

```
<%#= render ... %>
```

If your page works now (with missing parts), uncomment that line, have a look at the partial you are trying to render and repeat the process with 'render ...' in that one.

Finally you should be able to make out what caused the loop.

Comment: This was not my case exactly, but it's the same problem. I had a function that generates a model with some validation, if the model failed the validation on save, the function tries again.

There was one validation which was never passed, so the webrick went in an infinite cycle causing the application to freeze, but thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. In my case the problem was that I was creating indexes on the database (MongoDB 2.4.9) and that blocked the whole database. As soon the index creation was done the error message disappeared again. Obviously this error message appears if something is blocking.